# R - How to format a duration for proper sorting with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I have a dataframe which has durations in the column runtime.

```
>df
       value    runtime         info
1        129    4:52:05      sample1
3        145  1-5:12:43      sample2
```

I am unsure how to properly convert those durations to a format that is sortable e.g with dplyr arrange.

If I use the following I get a somewhat correct and sortable duration but with a date that is not needed, and also this only works for `%d-%H:%M:%S`, durations with `%H:%M:%S` are not correctly read and would need to be treated seperately.

```
>strptime('1-5:12:43',format='%d-%H:%M:%S')
[1] "2018-12-01 5:12:43 CET"
```

There is a `duration` function in the [`lubridate`](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/duration.html) package but it is not possible there to specify the input format of the duration.

I suppose I could come up with a clever regex statement to decompose the runtime string into its bits to use it like this:

```
>duration(second = 3, minute = 1.5, hour = 2, day = 6)
```

However before I do that, maybe there are other, easier suggestions?

Comment: What `1-5:12:43` means?

Comment: 1 day, 5 hours, 12 minutes, 43 seconds

Comment: Do you have control over the format of the runtime column?

Comment: No.. It is the output of a program that I cannot change unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort on strings as well, but the string as well as individual components need to be fixed width. You will need to do some string manipulation though. I don't see any other practical way:

```
rtimes<-c('1-5:12:43','4:52:05','32:05','2-23:59:59')

sortable<-sapply(rtimes,function(str){
  s<-as.numeric(
    unlist(
      strsplit(str,'-|:')
    )
  )
  v<-c(rep.int(0,4-length(s)),s) # Padding the vector to ensure 4 components
  paste(formatC(v,width = 2,flag = '0'),collapse = ' ') # PAdding the components to ensure 2 digits
},USE.NAMES = F)
sortable
[1] "01 05 12 43" "00 04 52 05" "00 00 32 05" "02 23 59 59"
sort(sortable)
"00 00 32 05" "00 04 52 05" "01 05 12 43" "02 23 59 59"
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can prepend the runtimes that do not have a day value with "0-" before doing the conversion? For instance by doing:

```
df$runtime[!grepl("-", df$runtime)] <- paste0(
"0-", df$runtime[!grepl("-", df$runtime)])
```

Afterwards you can sort on the times.

Comment: This won't work. The `%d` has to be greater than 0. `strptime('0-5:12:43',format='%d-%H:%M:%S')` will return `NA`